# Avoid hitting two different `.catch` blocks in a Promise

Tags: bluebird

With bluebird, let's say I want to catch an error and throw a different error.

```
DAO.getById('AccessTokens', token).then(function(matchingToken) {
  return matchingToken;
}).catch(NotFoundError, function(err) {
  Logging.error("caught a not found error"); // or some kind of logger...
  throw err;
}).catch(function(err) {
  throw ['DB Error - Tokens', err];
});
```

If I run this and a NotFoundError is thrown, I observe that the NotFoundError handler runs, then the generic error handler runs. I would like only the NotFoundError handler to run/propagate for a NotFoundError.

Is there a way to catch some errors and propagate them without also hitting the catchall error handler?

I could remove the catchall, but then it's possible for unknown errors to propagate. I could check for NotFoundErrors in the catchall, but that seems like duplicated behavior.. is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

#### No, but let's talk about why

Currently - no, it was considered in the past but the use case was not convincing enough at the moment. Petka Gorgi and I discussed it in IRC at a point and generally agreed that using `.catch(function(){` (a catch all) is not the greatest idea - not knowing what might fail is problematic and typically if you fail for a reason you don't know - you want to restart the server since it is unclear how you'd recover.

Personally, I'd just remove the catch-all - especially since it throws something that is not an error (so no stack trace, which is problematic and deteriorating in terms of debugging anyway). You can log errors globally and shut down gracefully.

#### I'm an adult and you're not the boss of me

Fine, you're right. The library is opinionated towards what I think are good error handling practices. Your opinion may vary and you can write a catch-all in the way you'd like. Sadly, I've been coding Haskell all day, so this might seem a little functional in style - you can always just catch types in the catch-all:

```
function typeT(type){
    return function(item){ return item instanceof type; };
}
function not(fn){
    return function(){ return !(fn.apply(this, arguments); };
}

DAO.getById('AccessTokens', token).then(function(matchingToken) {
  return matchingToken;
}).catch(NotFoundError, function(err) {
  Logging.error("caught a not found error"); // or some kind of logger...
  throw err;
}).catch(not(typeT(NotFoundError)), function(err) { // predicate function catch clause
  throw ['DB Error - Tokens', err];
});
```